# When attempting to run a function there is a prompt to select a macro

Tags: vba, function

I'm trying basic stuff from the book for dummies to see what it does.

```vb
Function CubeRoot(number)
    CubeRoot = number ^ (1 / 3)
End Function
    
Function Change(Cell, NewText)
    Cell.Comment.Text NewText
End Function
```

Both prompt me to select a macro. It is trying to suggest an unrelated sub.

```vb
Sub ShowMessage()
    MsgBox "THats all folks"  
End Sub
```

Comment: To use the functions,  you have to call them using parameters. For example: `Sub MySub()`, then `MsgBox CubeRoot(3)`, then `End Sub`.

Comment: You cannot run functions with `F5` like you can with Subs.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you cannot run the functions as the require an input. Try inserting this code into your module and it should make more sense. The answer to your question is that you cannot run your function without calling it.

```
Sub RunTHISMacro()

    MsgBox "This is the first macro which returns the cube root of 64 which is " & CubeRoot(64)


End Sub



Function CubeRoot(Number as Double) AS Double
     CubeRoot = Number ^ (1 / 3)
End Function
```